# Failsave Kubernetes with preemtible VMs in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Google has an offer called preemptible VMs which are VMs that do not guarantee to be available all the time and which are shut down once every 24 hours.

Our goal is to deploy a failsave (to a certain degree) kubernetes cluster with those VM by having enough backup VMs to handle the case that one VM is shutdown. [This](https://medium.com/pixboost/save-cash-by-running-kubernetes-services-on-preemptible-vms-in-google-cloud-cca02809ae09) article describe a simple scenario where preemptible VMs are used to run an image service. This scenario is simple because there is no database or message broker involved running on preemptible VMs.

Is it possible to run a whole (microservice-based) application including databases and message brokers with only preemptible VMs?

Further Questions that we have:

1. When do the preemptible VMs get shut down usually? Is it usually the case that if one VM gets shut down, all the other are too (at the same time)?
2. How log is the downtime of a preemptible VM getting restarted?

Any guidance that helps answering those questions and/or helping us configure such a cluster is apprechiated.

Comment: Looking here, it seems that a preemtible instance will be shutdown no later than 24 hours after it was started.  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible

Thus, if you wanted to stagger your worst case, you'd ensure that they start staggered.

My guess is that after 24 hours, an instance *might* be restarted immediately ... or after some indeterminate amount of time.  By their nature, you can't rely on a preemtable instance being available when you need it.

Comment: thanks for your response. The idea is to have multiple VM running. So that if one gets shut down, there is a backup VM in place. However, this scenario only works if it is unlikely that all VM get shutdown at the same time.

Comment: The idea behind preemptible VMs is to save on cost when you CAN get buy with fewer VMs than might at any given point be available in the preemptible pool.  If your solution requires a minimum number of VMs to be concurrently assured to be available, then you should ensure that there is always that number of non preemptible ones around.  Google doesn't assure that there will be ANY preemptible VMs at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions:

*1.-When do the preemptible VMs get shut down usually? Is it usually the case that if one VM gets shut down, all the other are too (at the same time)?*

**A**:The lifetime for preemptible VMs is no more than 24 hours, they can be shutdown whenever Google need the resources between this lifetime, find more information about limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#limitations). Resetting the counter means that you manually stop and start the instances, however keep in mind that the [selection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemption_selection) will preempt instances that were recently launched most recently.

*2.-How log is the downtime of a preemptible VM getting restarted?*

**A**: If you mean where you can see the logs of Compute Engine that notices you when an instance was terminated, you can use Stackdriver Logging.